# Encoding the multi-byte no-operation instruction (x86/x64)

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, machine-code

This instruction is on page 1018 of the intel x64 reference manual.  Here's what it looks like:

```
Opcode    Instruction Description
90        NOP         One byte no-operation instruction.
0F 1F /0  NOP r/m16   Multi-byte no-operation instruction.
0F 1F /0  NOP r/m32   Multi-byte no-operation instruction.
```

I read somewhere that the max no-op length is 9 bytes.  Is the no-op length in a 16/32 bit register or memory address or do I encode it with a bunch of zeroes myself and if so how does the r/m16 or r/m32 apply?

Comment: You can use the usual format for `/0 r/m` as indicated to encode any operand you want. Of course it won't be used, it is a NOP after all :) See also section _3.5.1.10 Using NOPs_ in the optimization manual.

Comment: You can make a NOP up to 15 bytes long with redundant prefixes, but that will be decoded slowly on Atom and Intel processors older than Core2, and most AMD processors (not Bobcat and Jaguar)

Comment: *Length* is (alas) not a parameter in Intel's opcodes. You must construct a *valid* r/m16/r/m32 argument that happens to encode to the correct length.

Answer (score 0):

From xed:

```
xed64 -64 -e NOP MEM4:EAX,EAX,1,00000000
OPERAND ORDER: MEM0 
Encodable! 670F18A40000000000
.byte 0x67,0x0f,0x18,0xa4,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
```

The advantage of using 9 byte nop is to reduce strain from the decoder, that can decode only 4 instructions per cycle. And NOP is technically an instruction.

Comment: Nice, but how to find a `nop` less than 9 bytes?

Comment: For example you can remove the 67 prefix to get 8 bytes. Use another addressing mode (2 src), or a one byte immediate. There are many combinations.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Is there a procedure to follow to find a *specific* length? Does it come down to entering different mod/rm bytes and assembling them to see if it's what one needs? That is what the OP asks -- his "padding with zeroes" idea will not work.

Comment: I found this page: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOP.html
The opcodes are valid, but according to xed, not exactly as described.

Comment: Check out Vol. 2B of  the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual": "Table 4-9. Recommended Multi-Byte Sequence of NOP Instruction" lists suggestions for 2 to 9 bytes.